# Tem alguma forma de acessar uma posição por meio de string?

Tags: c++, array, string

Não teria alguma forma de acessar uma posição utilizando uma *string*?
Exemplo:

```
int vetor[1000000];

vetor["abc"]++;
```

Eu sei que é loucura minha, mas... "abc" = 01100001, 01100010, 01100011, 00000000 (caractere null), então "abc" não deveria representar 1633837824?

Comment: Só fazer map<string, int> seuMap; seuMap["abc"] = 0; etc... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível através de um [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) ou [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), onde o índice pode ser propositalmente uma *string*. Mas onde se espera um valor inteiro não pode usar uma *string*, no máximo pode se usar algum algoritmo de conversão da *string* (pode ser um *cast*) para algum inteiro que faça sentido para utilização como índice. Então, sim, é "loucura" pensar que um texto poderia ser usado de forma direta em um índice de um *array*.

Fora o fato que nesse caso pegaria um local da memória que não pertence ao *array* declarado, pode fazer isto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int vetor[100000];
    vetor[(int)"a"] = 1; // é 0110000100000000
    cout << vetor[(int)"a"];
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/PositionByString.cpp).

Comment: Valeeeu! Eu tava querendo algo diferente do map por causa que ele é um pouco mais lento que um vetor, mas valeu ai :D